# How to access a button inside a nested repeater in ASP.net?

Tags: asp.net, button, nested, repeater

I have been trying to understand what is happening and I have searched the web to no avail.

How do I access my buttons that are inside of a nested repeater? I have spent so many hours researching/experimenting and I do not understand what is going on.

**HTML Markup:**

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repQuestionTopics">
    ....
    <asp:Repeater ID="repQA" runat="server">
        ....
        <strong>Was this article helpful?</strong>&nbsp; 
        <button class="button tiny secondary radius" runat="server" 
              CommandName="voteYes" id="btnVoteHelpfulYes">Yes</button> 
        <button class="button tiny secondary radius" runat="server" 
              CommandName="voteNo" ID="btnVoteHelpfulNo">No</button>
    </asp:Repeater>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Code-Behind:**

```
//Handles repQuestionTopics.ItemCommand
Public Sub repTopics_ItemCommand(Sender As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    If e.CommandName = "voteYes" Then
        ....
    End If
End Sub
```

How do I gain access to `repQA`? For some reason my code-behind will not let me write the function *Handles repQA.ItemCommand* - why? I have tried to directly input the function on the asp side by using something like (adding OnClick):

```
<button class="button tiny secondary radius" runat="server" OnClick="repTopics_ItemCommand"
        CommandName="voteYes" id="btnVoteHelpfulYes">Yes</button>
```

When the button `voteYes` is clicked I want to be able to go to the database and update the counter so I can keep track of how many up votes and down votes there are for that answer to the question.

No matter what change I implement to try and get it to work when I click the button the page refreshes and that is it - nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML Markup:** You have to add `OnItemCommand` event to your inner Repeater `repAQ`:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="repQA" runat="server" OnItemCommand="repQA_ItemCommand">
```

**Code-Behind:**

*VB.Net:*

```
Public Sub repQA_ItemCommand(Sender As Object, e As RepeaterCommandEventArgs)
    // check for right name of command
    If e.CommandName = "voteYes" Then
        ....
    End If
End Sub
```

*ASP.Net:*

```
protected void repQA_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    // check for right name of command
    if(e.CommandName == "voteYes")
    {
        ....
    }
}
```